# How do I document an object with JSDoc?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc, jsdoc3, code-documentation

What's the best way to document the source code of a simple JavaScript object (and its export) using  JSDoc?

For example, I want to document the following object:

```
/** how do I JSDocument object baseAdder? */
const baseAdder  = {
    /** how do I JSDocument property base? */
    base: 1,
    /**
     * Add a number to base
     * @param {number} a the number to be added to base
     * @returns {number} the sum of the number plus base
     */
    f: function(a) {
        return this.base + a;
        }
    };

/** how do I JSDocument this export? Should I? */
module.exports = baseAdder;
```

Answer (score 3):

A basic JS Doc documentation is like.

```
/*
* {Object} baseAdder - Base Adder object
* {Number} baseAdder.base - Base value
* {function} baseAdder.f - A function f on the Base Adder
*/
const baseAdder  = {
    base: 1,
    /**
     * Add a number to base
     * @param {Number} - a the number to be added to base
     * @returns {Number} - the sum of the number plus base
     */
    f: function(a) {
        return this.base + a;
        }
    };

/**
 * A module of base adder!
 * @module baseAdder
 */
module.exports = baseAdder;
```

For more reference follow the official documentation - http://usejsdoc.org/index.html

Comment: Thanks! I 've been to the jsdoc site  before but  I found it not that clear for  the top 5-liner you 've added.  
A quick question: Why we document  the function f both on top and inside the object?

Comment: The first one is just a meta info that object has a one key with value as function. In the inside it actually define the what parameter it's expected and return type. Frankly speaking it's more of a personal preference where do you want to place  it ( inner or top ) both are equally valid.

Answer (score 1):

> In most cases, your CommonJS or Node.js module should include a standalone JSDoc comment that contains a @module tag. The @module tag's value should be the module identifier that's passed to the require() function. For example, if users load the module by calling require('my/shirt'), your JSDoc comment would contain the tag @module my/shirt.

See [Documenting JavaScript Modules](https://jsdoc.app/howto-commonjs-modules.html)

A standalone JSDoc comment for that would be:

```js
/** @module so/answer */
```

Meaning that we would require your module as follow:

```js
const adder = require('so/answer');
```

Your `baseAdder` object is actually a namespace (see [`@namespace`](https://jsdoc.app/tags-namespace.html)) with two static members: a number and a function.

```js
/** @module so/answer */

/** @namespace */
const baseAdder  = {

  /**
   * @type {number}
   * @default 1
   */
  base: 1,

  /**
   * @param {number} a the number to be added to base
   * @return {number} the sum of the number plus base
   */
  f: function(a) {
    return this.base + a;
  }
};

module.exports = baseAdder;
```

Unless *explicitly* documented otherwise, all symbols within a module are members of that module. So your namespace now belongs to that module.

**Warning:** It is a common mistake to use `{Number}` instead of `{number}`. These are two different type expressions. The first refers to a number object e.g. `new Number(42)` and the second refers to a literal number e.g. `42`.

In practice, people looking at your documentation are likely to assume a literal number either way but this distinction becomes important if you use a static type checker based on JSDoc.

See also my [JSDoc Cheat Sheet](https://gist.github.com/customcommander/5206dcb44670e34f6923b62c1781e1d2) if you're interested.

---

What the doc looks like when generated via JSDoc

Index:

[image]

Let's see your module:

[image]

Let's see your namespace:

[image]