# JSDOC: How to document a function within of simple object

Tags: javascript, jsdoc, documentation-generation

I need to document a simple object and I'm failing to find a documentation or tutorial how to document `@param` and `@returns` for the inner methods. If I put them above the respective method (`xyz`), they are ignored, if I put them above the object, `@param` is not assigned (or I have no idea how to assign it here).

Let's say it's a simple object, like this:

```
export const foo = {

  abc: 'A string',

  xyz: (x) => {
    return x + '!'
  }

}
```

I expected something like this should work:

```
/**
 * @module FooModule
 */

/**
 * @type {object}
 */ 

export const foo = {

 /**
   * @property {string} abc - some property
   */ 
  abc: 'A string',

 /**
   * @property {function} xyz - some method
   * @param {string} x - source string
   * @returns {string} - exclamation mark added
   */ 
  xyz: (x) => {
    return x + '!'
  }

}
```

But it doesn't work, obviously. I've found a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53122176/how-do-i-document-an-object-with-jsdoc/65974050#65974050) but the solution is wrong, it doesn't work at all. How should this be done correctly, so that I get a module `FooModule`, a global constant `foo` with `foo.abc` property and `foo.xyz` method (incl. `@param` and `@returns`) in the output JSDoc?

Can it be done? If yes, can it be done without `@typedef`ing all functions like this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the [latest answer to other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65974353/15114420) found the problem. It's not in the JSDoc syntax, but in the javascript itself. It seems JSDoc's `@module` can't be used with the `export` directive. If `@module` is removed, the documentation works as expected. If `@module` is used, the `export` must be replaced by

```
module.exports = foo
```

at the end. Then the JSDoc build works fine.

Comment: Hey brother any luck with jsdoc?